# Not able to comprehend 2d matrix result python

Tags: python-3.x, matrix, 2d

I'm inputting a 2-D matrix and I'm trying  to add 3 zeros to each column and row at both starting and end.

```
arr2d = [[j for j in input().split(' ')] for i in range(20)] 
arr1d = [0]*len(arr2d)
array = []

for j in range(3):
    arr2d.insert(0,arr1d)
    arr2d.insert(len(arr2d),arr1d)
for k in range(len(arr2d)):
    for i in range(3):
        arr2d[k].append(0)
        arr2d[k].insert(0,0)
```

My input is this.

[image: input]

but instead I'm getting the following output.

[image: output]

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the example input & output directly, rather than giving links. This would make it easier for other people to read, and suggest solutions. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `arr2d.insert(0,arr1d)`, you're not inserting a *copy* of `arr1d`; you're inserting `arr1d` *itself*.  Later on when you do things like `arr2d[k].append(0)` with, say, `k = 0`, since `arr2d[0]` is `arr1d`, you're modifying `arr1d` (which is also `arr2d[1]` and also `arr2d[2]` and so forth).  So any zeroes being added to the front or back of the first and last 3 rows are being added to *all* of them.

Here's a simpler example to illustrate exactly what's happening:

```
>>> A = [[0]] * 5
>>> A
[[0], [0], [0], [0], [0]]
>>> A[0][0] = 7
>>> A
[[7], [7], [7], [7], [7]]
```